# Qt Android Two Overlapping Videos

Tags: android, c++, qt, video

The eventual goal is to create an application that has two videos that are transparent overlapping eachother for some cool effects.

The problem I face is I can't figure out how to play two videos at the same time.

The base for my project is in the Qt examples: http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtmultimedia-multimedia-video-qmlvideo-example.html

I am starting with searching for two .wmv videos in the file browser, and selecting the "Multi" button under Video Modes. I am able to play the first video in the left hand screen, and the second video on the right hand side, however, when I start the second video with the first one already playing, the first one stops.

I would like to have both videos playing.

Can anyone offer a solution to modify the example code to have two videos playing at the same time?

I will work on overlapping them and changing the alpha later.

Any help is appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: Related for native Android: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25882800/play-two-videos-in-one-videoview-at-the-same-time

Comment: Thanks for the quick response. I had read that thread and it does not involve using Qt.